GitGraph extension for VSCode not showing in the bottom status bar
Although it is installed/enabled, since about 2 weeks it is not showing in my VSCode the bottom status bar.
I observed the same problem about 2 weeks ago on older (maintained) installation of MS Windows 10 and VSCode.
Then - for another reason - I had to freshly install windows 10, VSCode, all extensions, yet I still observe the same problem. It seems to work well on Linux Ubuntu.
There has been reported problem here quite long ago and folks seem to mention this great extension is no longer being maintained.
Yet, I'd like to find/expose a general workaround for the benefit of many (and me).
I can't see a good solution on that problem reporting site. Did I miss something ?
Can anyone share his/her workaround please ?
E.G.: If not fix it directly, then how to display the graph other way than from the bottom bar ?

Showing in status bar is enabled:

But it is not even listed among extensions to display:


Suddenly - not knowing exactly how it happen - I got the GitGraph option there. The only significant change is, that I installed .net6.0 , which is the target fwk for the currently open project, whereas before I had only had .net8.0  installed.
Then I was able to run automated tests and now I have noticed, I got the GitGraph 'button' back on the bottom status bar :)

if you uninstall .net6.0, does the problem come back? does the same problem happen in project workspaces that don't require .net?

@starball  Nope - I tried to uninstall 6.0 and GitGraph is still there. Its just that I can't run unit tests targeted for 6.0 until I reinstall again.

Probably your Git repository is in a sub folder. Go to extension settings for Git Graph and search for "Git-graph: Max Depth Of Repo Search", it must be zero in your case right now. Change it to your desired number. Also, please let me know if this works!

Hi, thanks for the note.
I can't as the problem is not reproducible at the moment.
